# efficient way to access keys of JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json

In java, if you have a `JSONObject` with deeply nested keys/values like the one below.

Is there an efficient way to extract the value for a key that is deeply nested (e.g. for `object4` below) without having to do something along the lines of `obj.getJSONObject("object1").getetJSONObject("object2").getJSONObject("object3").getJSONObject("object4")`?

```
{
    "object1": {
        "object2": {
            "object3": {
                "object4": "value to extract"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make classes for the json and then directly map the JSON to that class. Although you will still need getter methods for extracting the data. But making a class will help you understand and debug your code easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JSONPath library.](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

In your case, you'd write `JsonPath.read(json.toString(), "object1.object2.object3.object4")`6.

Comment: Why is it more efficient ?

Comment: Efficient as in needing lesser code to write - because you don't need to write `obj.getJSONObject("object1").getetJSONObject("object2").getJSONObject("object3").getJSONObject("object4")` along with checks for existence of key.